# R How to extract info from xml tags

Tags: python, xml, r, perl, spaces

I have a question regarding xml parsing.
I have tags with spaces in e.g.

```
<item1 id=rt name ="th">
<point1>1254</point1>
<point2>1254</point2>
</item>
```

How do I extract the id and name out of this tags?

I'm now using R as I need for the rest of my analysis, but I can also do file parsing in perl and python.
What is the best solution?

Comment: is this the real data? The first tag is not well-formed XML, it's lacking the quotes around the id value. If that's the data you have, you probably won't be able to use XML tools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this for example, using `XML` package:

```
tt <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item id="rt" name ="th">
  <point1>1254</point1>
  <point2>1254</point2>
</item>
'

library(XML)
xpathSApply(doc,'//item',xmlGetAttr,'id')
[1] "rt"
```

**EDIT**

In case your data is not well formatted, you should reformat your data as I did above or read your data line by line , and extract the information using some regular expression ( not recommended with XML tags to use regex)

```
    tt <- '<item1 id=rt name ="th">
<point1>1254</point1>
<point2>1254</point2>
</item>
    '

    ll <- readLines(textConnection(tt))
    gsub('.*id=(.*)[ ]name.*','\\1',ll[1])
 [1] "rt"
```

Comment: You changed the input. As @mirod pointed out above, the input does not have `id="rt"` but `id=rt`.

Comment: @simbabque yes , I know the XML is really bad formatted ( se item1 tag not item). My answer is to show the R beginner user how to use XML package.

Comment: Fair enough. In that case I suggest point that out (which you did now). Otherwise, they might complain it is not working. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about a regex?

`/=\K\W?\K\w+/g`

`=\K` finds but does not save the `=`

`\W?\K` finds but does not save the potential quotation mark before your tag.

`\w+` is your tag.

You can read the file line by line and save your matches into an array, something like:

`my @matches = $line =~ /=\K\W?\K\w+/g;`

And then use `$matches[]` to access the individual elements.

Here it the regex in action if you want to play with it further:
http://regexr.com?37im8